# Ruby threads: how to catch an exception without calling .join?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

How to observe and rescue an error that happens in the thread without using `.join`? The code that I have right now:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
begin
    a = Thread.new { errory_code }
rescue Exception => detail
    puts detail.message
end

sleep 1 #so that thread has enough time to execute
```

If I understand it correctly, `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` aborts thread execution (that is, raises an exception). But why rescue doesn't catch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it - I just need to wrap insides of my thread into a rescue block like that:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

a = Thread.new do 
    begin                      #new
        errory_code 
    rescue Exception => detail #new
        puts detail.message    #new
    end                        #new
end

sleep 1 #so that thread has enough time to execute
```

Which is a horribly obvious solution, - but, since it took me so long to think of it, will hopefully help somebody.

Answer (score 3):

You're expecting the `rescue` operation to catch exceptions from a bit of code that's run long after Ruby's exited that `begin ... end` block. That's not going to happen.

Remember when you're dealing with threads, things happen out of order.

The only exceptions you can catch there are those relating to the creation of the thread. What happens inside the thread is a whole other world.

Using `join` forces your code to wait until the thread is complete, so that gets the ordering correct. Thread exceptions can then be caught.

Comment: Hm. Is there any other ordering method then? (I can't use `.join`, because many joins will need to be in different places - which will cause them to wait for one another to complete). Can I have two separate threads in different places and catch exceptions in them and know in what thread that exception happened?

Comment: The threads won't wait, but your outer thread management code will. If you need them all to complete before you can continue, there's no harm in calling `join` on each one util they've all wrapped up. That will simply wait for the longest-running one to complete regardless of order.

Comment: In this case: `a = Thread.new { 5.times { |i| p i; sleep 0.3 } };
a.join;
b = Thread.new { 5.times { |k| p k } };
b.join;` b thread will wait for a thread to complete before starting sadly.

Comment: Any point you have a  `join` that will halt execution until the sub-thread is finished. Instead just do `a.join; b.join` at the end. General rule: Don't wait on a thread until you need to.